# ¿Como puedo quitar estos cachos blancos de mi web?

Tags: html, css

Aunque no puedo ver bien los estilos de tu código, se el motivo por lo cual no te funciona, la etiqueta `<h1>` de HTML maneja unos margenes por defecto los cuales si los quitas sera la solución a tu problema, la margen de arriba si la visualizo solucionada la de abajo no la puedo distinguir por que no se visualizan bien los estilos pero visualizalo con los tuyos y me cuentas.

```css
#izenburua{
  width: 100%;
  text-align:   center;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
 }
 .navbar navbar-inverse{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
  
  h1{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom:0;
  }
```

```html
 <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <header id="izenburua">
    <h1>ASK/ANSWER</h1>
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav> 
  
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://silenttruth.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/happy-people.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://s-i.huffpost.com/gen/3866236/images/o-HAPPY-facebook.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://s-i.huffpost.com/gen/1813932/images/o-HAPPY-facebook.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
  <footer>
  
  </footer>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo importar polita.css y bootstrap.min.css desde un servidor para poder ver los estilos correctamente en el snippet

Comment: De hecho hacer .navbar .navbar-inverse no tiene sentido por que ambos son clases del mismo elemento, puede dejar solo .navbar

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Bootstrap usas?

Comment: La última versión que no es beta (la anterior a la 4.0).

Comment: No entiendo que dices sobre que estén mal los estilos, no hay nada más que eso

Comment: Lo he editado ya

Comment: Por favor edita bien tu pregunta... haz copiado la respuesta como pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usas el inspector de elementos te podrás dar cuenta de las márgenes que tienes los elementos y así sabrás a que elemento se la debes quitar.

Tienes esta línea `.navbar navbar-inverse{` la cual primero que todo está mal escrita (falta el `.` en `navbar-inverse`) y segundo que todo no tiene sentido por que `.navbar` y `.navbar-inverse` son el mismo elemento en tu flujo de nodos.

Podrías agregar un identificador único a tu `.navbar` que podría ser `#menu_principal` y aplicar los estilos necesarios sobre ese identificador.

Ahora te digo que no es recomendable hacer esto:

```
h1{
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Estarías quitando las márgenes a todos los h1 de tu sitio y sería un problema si en algunos las necesitaras, lo mejor es seleccionar el padre del elemento y luego el elemento para que los estilos se apliquen únicamente al elemento que necesitas.

Acá te dejo tu código completo:

```css
#izenburua{
  width: 100%;
  text-align:   center;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#izenburua h1{
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#menu_principal{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta name="tipo_contenido" content="text/html;" http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="../CSS/polita.css" media="all"/>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header id="izenburua">
    <h1>ASK/ANSWER</h1>
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="menu_principal">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav> 
  
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://silenttruth.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/happy-people.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://s-i.huffpost.com/gen/3866236/images/o-HAPPY-facebook.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://s-i.huffpost.com/gen/1813932/images/o-HAPPY-facebook.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
  <footer>
  
  </footer>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: los mismo que dices del elemento `h1` es para la clase `.navbar` de bootstrap... obligas a todos no tener un margen-bottom... no sería mejor de evitar: `!important` ?

Comment: @aldanux tienes razón, y sin el important sigue cogiendo el margin-bottom: 20px que agrega bootstrap a esa clase

Comment: Simple solución: `.navbar.otraclase{ .. }` y te olvidas del important ;)

Comment: @aldanux es una buena solución pero me surge una duda, que tiene de malo usar !important ?

Comment: En principio no es malo usarlo (si no no existiría). [Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad#La_excepción_!important) tienes una breve explicación... aunque dice que la puedes usar para las librerías externas como Bootstrap pero en este caso no es necesario de usar `!important`...en vez usa(ría) selectores más específicos y tendrás el `.navbar` con sus estilos originales y sin el uso de `!important`... la cuestión es usar `!important` cuando de verdad sea necesario

Comment: @aldanux gracias por las aclaraciones he mejorado la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no puedo ver bien los estilos de tu código, se el motivo por lo cual no te funciona, la etiqueta `<h1>` de HTML maneja unos margenes por defecto los cuales si los quitas sera la solución a tu problema, la margen de arriba si la visualizo solucionada la de abajo no la puedo distinguir por que no se visualizan bien los estilos pero visualizalo con los tuyos y me cuentas.

```css
#izenburua{
  width: 100%;
  text-align:   center;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
 }
 .navbar navbar-inverse{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
  
  h1{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom:0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta name="tipo_contenido" content="text/html;" http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="../CSS/polita.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header id="izenburua">
    <h1>ASK/ANSWER</h1>
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav> 
  
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://silenttruth.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/happy-people.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://s-i.huffpost.com/gen/3866236/images/o-HAPPY-facebook.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://s-i.huffpost.com/gen/1813932/images/o-HAPPY-facebook.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
  <footer>
  
  </footer>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo he probado pero no me ha funcionado

Comment: @MikelMolinuevo el de abajo? puedes importar los estilos que faltan para poder visualizar bien

Comment: Te lo he editado sin querer, perdón